# Form data for iHotelier

Tags: web, forms

I developed a website for a resort and put a reservation form on the home page.  I am trying to get the Arrival, Departure, Room #, Adult # & Child # to go from the from to the iHotelier page.

The home page with the reservation form is: http://blueharborresort.com
The iHotelier page is: https://booking.ihotelier.com/istay/istay.jsp?hotelid=76029

Answer (score 1):

Recently came across this website that details exactly what you're asking about.
http://hummelinteractive.com/ihotelier-by-travelclick-how-to-post-data-to-their-reservation-engine

....

The main thing to know is that the ihotelier application accepts GET data in a certain formation as follows:

- DateIn
- DateOut
- Adults
- Children
- Rooms
- HotelID
- LanguageID

....